# How to append the data into data frame generated by a loop in python and beutifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Below loop supposes to add multiple table's row (html page) in one dataframe. loop works fine, it creates a dataframe for each table one by one but it also replaces previous table's data from dataframe which is i want to fix. it should append each table's data into the same dataframe, It should not replace previous table's data from dataframe. Plase help me on this.

```
column_headers = ['state', 'sr_no', 'district_name', 'country']

headers = ['district_id']

    district_link = [[li.get('href') for li in data_rows_link[i].findAll('a')]
               for i in range(len(data_rows))]

district_data_02 = []  # create an empty list to hold all the data

for i in range(len(data_rows)):  # for each table row
    district_row = []  # create an empty list for each pick/player
    district_row.append("a")

    # for each table data element from each table row
    for li in data_rows[i].findAll('li'):
        # get the text content and append to the district_row
        district_row.append(li.getText())

    # then append each pick/player to the district_data matrix
    district_data_02.append(district_row)

district_data == district_data_02

#dataframe - districtlist
districtlist = pd.DataFrame(district_data ,columns=column_headers)

districtid = pd.DataFrame(district_link, columns=headers)

#df_row_merged = pd.concat([df, df1])

#dataframe - districtid
final_districtlist =pd.concat([districtlist, districtid], axis=1)
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `district_data == district_data_02` line?

Comment: The code you provided is not complete. You say, that you're iterating more than one table. Are those tables within several documents to be parsed or all in one? If you load several documents, than your final_districtlist must be outside that loop otherwise it's obvious that it gets overwritten after parsing one table.